# node mariasql query won't terminate / does the mariadb.end() funciton wait for all the queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb

I am running the following script with node:

```
var mariadb = require("mariasql");
var db = new mariadb();
db.connect({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "bus1708v2.0",
    db: "test"
});

db.query("INSERT INTO Persons (LastName, FirstName) VALUES ('Some', 'Name')")
    .on("result", function(result){
        result.on("end", function(info){
            console.log(info);
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
```

It successfully inserts into the database but I have to press ctrl-c to terminate the script

### Update

I just realized i need to put 
    db.end(); 
at the very end

In this case does db.end() wait for all the queries to finish?

Comment: I updated my answer to match your updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling

```
db.end();
```

once you're done with writing into the database, as the driver keeps the connection open and hence prevents Node.js from shutting down. So your code should be

```
db.query("INSERT INTO Persons (LastName, FirstName) VALUES ('Some', 'Name')")
    .on("result", function(result){
        result.on("end", function(info){
            console.log(info);
            console.log(result);
            db.end();
        });
    });
```

Alternatively, simply put the call to `db.end();` into the very last line of your sample. According to the documentation, the driver only closes the connection once all queued commands have been run.

Comment: Oh. I found db.end() before your answer but it didn't occur to me to put it there.It makes sense I guess. What if I put it after the db.query call? Would it block until all the queries are finished?

Comment: I don't know that, to be true. But to be sure that everything was written correctly, I'd try to defer its call until all the callbacks were run.

Comment: Okay, from the docs: `end() => Closes the connection once all queries in the queue have been executed.`, so it should be okay if you put it simply in the last line of your file. All the samples in the documentation do this as well.